# ses.sendmail() gives CORS error. 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*'..credentials mode is 'include'

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, cors, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-ses

I have been stuck on this for 4 days now. I really need some insights.

I have a serverless express app deployed on AWS. I am serving my frontend from S3 and backend from lambda. API gateway has proxy as shown in the serverless.yml below.

I have also used cloudfront to map my domain(https://my.domain.com.au) with the S3 bucket origin URL.

The normal GET POST PUT DELETE requests are working fine. But when I try to access any of the other AWS service from Lambda I get following CORS error.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://0cn0ej4t5w.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/prod/api/auth/reset-password' from origin 'https://my.domain.com.au' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

My use case is to send a mail from my app for which I tried using.

```
ses.sendEmail(params).promise();
```

This gave me the same error. So i tried invoking it through lambda, same error. Now i am trying to push mail contents to S3 and send mail from lambda using trigger but this gave me the same error.

The issue doesn't seem to be on the code as its working perfect from local environment. However, i don't want to leave any stones unturned.

Since, my lambda is in a VPC i have used internet gateway and tried setting up the private link as well.

Serverless.yml

```
service: my-api

# plugins 
plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin

# custom for secret inclusions
custom:
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  serverless-offline:
    httpPort: 5000
  webpack:
    webpackConfig: ./webpack.config.js
    includeModules: # enable auto-packing of external modules
      forceInclude:
        - mysql
        - mysql2 
        - passport-jwt
        - jsonwebtoken
        - moment
        - moment-timezone
        - lodash

# provider
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  # you can overwrite defaults here
  stage: prod
  region: ${env:AWS_REGION_APP}
  timeout: 10
  iamManagedPolicies:
    - 'arn:aws:iam::777777777777777:policy/LambdaSESAccessPolicy'
  vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
      - ${env:AWS_SUBNET_GROUP_ID}
    subnetIds:
      - ${env:AWS_SUBNET_ID1}
      - ${env:AWS_SUBNET_ID2}
      - ${env:AWS_SUBNET_ID3}
  environment:
    /// env variables (hidden)
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - s3:*
        - ses:*
        - lambda:*
      Resource: '*'

# functions
functions:
  app:
    handler: server.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: /
          method: ANY
      - http:
          path: /{proxy+}
          method: ANY
          cors:
            origin: ${env:CORS_ORIGIN_URL}
            allowCredentials: true
            headers: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization'
            method: ANY

# you can add CloudFormation resource templates here
resources:
  # API Gateway Errors
  - ${file(resources/api-gateway-errors.yml)}
  # VPC Access for RDS
  - ${file(resources/lambda-vpc-access.yml)}
```

I have configured response headers as well:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", process.env.CORS_ORIGIN_URL);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,DELETE");
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually have the same exact error as you but I've figured it out.

I'll just paste my code since you didn't show what your lambda function looks like.

I also know its been two weeks... so hopefully this helps someone in the future.

CORS errors are server side, and I'm sure you are aware. The problem with AWS SES is you have to handle the lambda correctly or it'll give you a cors error even though you have the right headers.

First things first... I don't think you have OPTIONS method in your api gateway...although I'm not sure if ANY can work as a replacement.

Second here is my code:
I check which http method I'm getting then I respond based on that. I am receiving a post event and some details come in the body. You might want to change the finally block to something else. The OPTIONS is important for the CORS, it lets the browser know that its okay to send the POST request (or at least that's how I see it)

```
var ses = new AWS.SES();

var RECEIVER = 'receiver@gmail.com';
var SENDER = 'sender@gmail.com';

exports.handler = async(event) => {

  let body;
  let statusCode = '200';
  const headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,DELETE,POST,PATCH,OPTIONS',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'access-control-allow-credentials,access-control-allow-headers,access-control-allow-methods,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,authorization,content-type',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  };
  console.log(event);

  try {
    switch (event.httpMethod) {
      case 'POST':
        event = JSON.parse(event.body);
        var params = {
          Destination: {
            ToAddresses: [
              RECEIVER
            ]
          },
          Message: {
            Body: {
              Html: {
                Data: html(event.name, event.phone, event.email, event.message), // 'Name: ' + event.name + '\nPhone: ' + event.phone + '\nEmail: ' + event.email + '\n\nMessage:\n' + event.message,
                Charset: 'UTF-8'
              }
            },
            Subject: {
              Data: 'You Have a Message From ' + event.name,
              Charset: 'UTF-8'
            }
          },
          Source: SENDER
        };
        await ses.sendEmail(params).promise();
        break;
      case 'OPTIONS':
        statusCode = '200';
        body = "OK";
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error(`Unsupported method "${event.httpMethod}"`);
    }
  }
  catch (err) {
    statusCode = '400';
    body = err.message;
  }
  finally {
    body = "{\"result\": \"Success\"}"
  }
 
  console.log({
    statusCode,
    body,
    headers,
  })
  return {
    statusCode,
    body,
    headers,
  };

}
```